# How to extract the last of a line if it is digit

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a text file below, trying to extract string if last part of line is digit

```
4:16:09PM - xx yy DOS activity from 10.0.0.45
9:43:44PM - xx yy 1A disconnected from server
2:40:28AM - xx yy 1A connected
1:21:52AM - xx yy DOS activity from 192.168.123.4
```

My Code

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\test.log') as f:
    for line in f:
        dos= re.findall(r'\d',line.split()[-1])
        print (list(dos))
```

My Out

```
['1', '0', '0', '0', '4', '5']
[]
[]
['1', '9', '2', '1', '6', '8', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Expected

`['10.0.0.45','192.168.123.4']`

Comment: why are you splitting `line`?

Comment: @MichaelSilverstein, i want to check the last portion of the line

Comment: Is the last part always an IP address?

Answer (score 3):

I guess,

```
(?m)(?:\d+\.){3}\d+$
```

might simply extract those desired IPs.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q4qoD3/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

string = '''
4:16:09PM - xx yy DOS activity from 10.0.0.45
9:43:44PM - xx yy 1A disconnected from server
2:40:28AM - xx yy 1A connected
1:21:52AM - xx yy DOS activity from 192.168.123.4
'''

expression = r'(?m)(?:\d+\.){3}\d+$'


print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
['10.0.0.45', '192.168.123.4']
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/q4qoD3/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/q4qoD3/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

could also take this approach, also implementing the check as to whether or not the last character in the line is a digit:

```
with open('test.log') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip()[-1].isdigit():
            dos = re.findall('[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+',line)
            print(dos)
```

output:

```
['10.0.0.45']
['192.168.123.4']
```

to put them into one list you can define an empty list and continually append to it if desired